# Function English is also performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this code in Javascript. But now I have a problem. This code checks if the page is English or Dutch. But when the page is English. The function in Dutch is also performed. How can i fix this?

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
// Diferent language
if (theLanguage === "en") {
    function doCheckForm() {
        el = document.getElementById('hoteliers');
        if (el) {
            el.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + document.hcomForm.hTarget.value + '" src="" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0">';
        }
    }
}

if (theLanguage === "nl") {
    function doCheckForm() {
        el = document.getElementById('hoteliers');
        if (el) {
            el.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + document.hcomForm.hTarget.value + '" src="" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0">';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the differnece between the two variants of doCheckForm() ?

Comment: so you have an array of `lang` attributes?

Comment: You have nothing to execute but two (identical?) function definitions... :-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out, `doCheckForm()` looks the same in both `if` statements. Regardless, I would recommend you strip out the function and do this:

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');

function doCheckForm() {
    el = document.getElementById('hoteliers');

    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + document.hcomForm.hTarget.value + '" src="" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0">';
    }
}

// Diferent language
if (theLanguage === "en") {
    doCheckForm();
} else if (theLanguage === "nl") {
    doCheckForm()    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is double `doCheckForm` declaration. Then your script context parsing by browser javascript engine functions init immediately and first. After functions init variables, but values assign to vars only in that code place, where is `=` operator.

Try this:

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');

function doCheckForm() {
    var el;
    if (theLanguage === "en") {
        el = document.getElementById('hoteliers');
        if (el) {
            el.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + document.hcomForm.hTarget.value + '" src="" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0">';
        }
    } else if (theLanguage === "nl") {
        /* Note: code was the same in your example*/
        el = document.getElementById('hoteliers');
        if (el) {
            el.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + document.hcomForm.hTarget.value + '" src="" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0">';
        }
    }
}

doCheckForm();
```